# Regex or C# solution to seperate Date/Time and log string with linebreaks

Tags: c#, regex

Here is an sample my log file I am trying to parse via Regex or C#

```
2015-04-22 10:08:01.99 Updated version to : 1.0.5590.18236
2015-04-22 10:08:02.00 LOG -------------------------------------------- START

2015-04-22 10:08:03.57 Server is listening at 0.0.0.0 port 25
2015-04-22 10:08:03.61 Web Interface started on localhost:2500
2015-04-22 10:09:29.76  >>> 220 Mailserver ready
2015-04-22 10:09:29.78  <<< EHLO none.vi
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> 250-Nice to meet you.
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS
250 SIZE
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> blah blah 
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> Relay Denied
Spamuolus
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81 Yadda Yadda
```

What I want to do is separate the datetime and message string even if it has multiple-lines and make it an array.
With Regex this is what I have so far `(\d+\-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+)\s(.*)` I get the date and the message string handled but the strings on multiple lines is a problem for me.
That pattern fails when it meets a `\n`
How would I do this in either C# or Regex ...

Comment: Please show the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, `2015-04-22 10:09:29.81` is DateTime (1st group) and the rest is the 2nd group in:

```
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> 250-Nice to meet you.
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS
250 SIZE
```

Then, you'd need a tricky regex like this:

```
(\d+(?:\-\d+){2}\s\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)\s([\s\S]*?)(?=$|\d+(?:\-\d+){2}\s\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)
```

No specific flags are required since newline is captured with `[\s\S]`.

C# code:

```
var rgxx = new Regex(@"(\d+(?:\-\d+){2}\s\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)\s([\s\S]*?)(?=$|\d+(?:\-\d+){2}\s\d+(?::\d+){2}\.\d+)");
var sttr = @"2015-04-22 10:08:01.99 Updated version to : 1.0.5590.18236
    2015-04-22 10:08:02.00 LOG -------------------------------------------- START

    2015-04-22 10:08:03.57 Server is listening at 0.0.0.0 port 25
    2015-04-22 10:08:03.61 Web Interface started on localhost:2500
    2015-04-22 10:09:29.76  >>> 220 Mailserver ready
    2015-04-22 10:09:29.78  <<< EHLO none.vi
    2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> 250-Nice to meet you.
    250-8BITMIME
    250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS
    250 SIZE
    2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> blah blah 
    2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> Relay Denied
    Spamuolus
    2015-04-22 10:09:29.81 Yadda Yadda";
var resss = rgxx.Matches(sttr).Cast<Match>().Select(p => new { dt = p.Groups[1].Value, desc = p.Groups[2].Value }).ToList();
```

[image]

Tested in Expresso:

[image]

BTW, in your regex a period in `\d+.\d+` is *any symbol*, not a literal period.

Answer (score 1):

So fluent it almost speaks for its self...

```
void Example()
{   
    Regex logRegex = new Regex(@"(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}\s\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{2} )");

    int order = 0;
    var logs = logString.Split('\n')
                        .Select(log => new 
                        {
                            TimeOfLog  = logRegex.Match(log).Groups[1].Value,
                            LogMessage = logRegex.Replace(log, string.Empty)
                            Order = logRegex.Match(log).Success ? ++order : order
                        })
                        .GroupBy(log => log.Order)
                        .Select(log => new Log 
                        {
                            TimeOfLog = DateTime.Parse(log.First().TimeOfLog),
                            LogMessage = string.Join(" ", log.Select(selector => selector.LogMessage))
                        });

}

public class Log
{
    public DateTime TimeOfLog { get; set; }
    public string LogMessage { get; set; }
}

public const string logString = @"2015-04-22 10:08:01.99 Updated version to : 1.0.5590.18236
2015-04-22 10:08:02.00 LOG -------------------------------------------- START

2015-04-22 10:08:03.57 Server is listening at 0.0.0.0 port 25
2015-04-22 10:08:03.61 Web Interface started on localhost:2500
2015-04-22 10:09:29.76  >>> 220 Mailserver ready
2015-04-22 10:09:29.78  <<< EHLO none.vi
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> 250-Nice to meet you.
250-8BITMIME
250-AUTH=CRAM-MD5 PLAIN LOGIN ANONYMOUS
250 SIZE
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> blah blah 
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81  >>> Relay Denied
Spamuolus
2015-04-22 10:09:29.81 Yadda Yadda ";
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `RegexOptions.Singleline`.

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(input, @"^(\d+\-\d+-\d+\s\d+:\d+:\d+.\d+)\s(.*)",
    RegexOptions.Singleline |   // . matches every character, including \n
    RegexOptions.Multiline);    // ^ matches beginning of any line
```

I have also added `^` (with `RegexOptions.Multiline`) to the beginning of your pattern so that it doesn't inadvertently match timestamps occurring at the middle of your line. Note that `Singleline` and `Multiline` [can be used together](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/singleline-multiline-confusing), despite their misleading names.

Answer (score 0):

```
What I want to do is separate the datetime and message string even if it has multiple-lines and make it an array
```

I can do that for you... This will give you a string[] variable (lines) that are split on each time a date begins a line

```
var logText = File.ReadAllText(fileName);
var lines = Regex.Split(logText, @"\r\n(?=[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2})");
```

[DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/KF7Wc4) -- Please note I had to change the \r\n to \n in the example because it doesn't take the typical \r\n when I manually plugged in your text